# Got exception when running the localhost cluster

Tags: java, localhost, apache-flink

I'm new to Flink. I got a problem when running the local cluster on my computer. Some key software information as follows:

- Flink version: 1.13.0 for Scala 2.11;
- OS: Fedora 34;
- Java version: 16;
- Scala version: 2.11.12.

When I started up the local cluster by command line, everything seems fine from the command line, BUT I could not access the `localhost:8081`. It fails to open. Furthermore, the exception comes out when I running the Flink example:

```
[root@localhost flink-1.13.0]# ./bin/start-cluster.sh
Starting cluster.
Starting standalonesession daemon on host fedora.
Starting taskexecutor daemon on host fedora.
```

```
[root@localhost flink-1.13.0]# ./bin/flink run examples/streaming/WordCount.jar
Executing WordCount example with default input data set.
Use --input to specify file input.
Printing result to stdout. Use --output to specify output path.

------------------------------------------------------------
 The program finished with the following exception:

org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: Unable to make field private final byte[] java.lang.String.value accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @2baf3d81
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:372)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222)
at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:114)
at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:812)
at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:246)
at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun(CliFrontend.java:1054)
at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1132)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:28)
at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1132)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final byte[] java.lang.String.value accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @2baf3d81
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:177)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:171)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:106)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:132)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:132)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:69)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.clean(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2053)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.clean(DataStream.java:203)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.addSink(DataStream.java:1243)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.print(DataStream.java:937)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.examples.wordcount.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:94)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355)
... 8 more
```

I tried search solutions online, but nothing useful for me so far.

Comment: This is a problem with the modules system introduced in Java 9. At least one of the modules - most likely one of Flink's or your's - is not recognized as a module and also not put onto the module path explicitly (which would make it an "automatic" instead of an "unnamed" module). I can't tell you how to change your deployment since I don't know Flink or your setup but that should get you into the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flink does not support Java 16. You'll need either Java 8 or 11.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have changed to Java 8, and it works fine now :)